# Requiring an optimized module after optimizing with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, requirejs

Upon starting my server, I'm attempting to utilize the RequireJS optimizer to combine all my RequireJS modules into a single file. Once the optimizer is finished, I am attempting to utilize the modules but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: __dirname,
    nodeRequire: require
});

requirejs.optimize({
    baseUrl: path.join(__dirname, 'foo'),
    dir: 'build',
    modules: [{
        name: 'main',
        include: [ 'src/bar' ]
    }]
}, function (data) {
    console.log(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'main.js'), 'utf-8'));
    var main = requirejs('/build/main.js'));
    var bar = requirejs('src/bar');
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

The output from the console.log is the concatenated files as expected, but bar is undefined.

If I run the following script after the previous script, bar is defined.

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: __dirname,
    nodeRequire: require
});

var main = requirejs('/build/main.js'));
var bar = requirejs('src/bar');
console.log(bar);
```

Can anyone offer any insight into what may be preventing the first script from working?

Thanks,
Jake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your path for `baseUrl` in `requirejs.config` was wrong. I've also added `removeCombined` in the optimizer configuration to prevent loading files that have been combined into `main`.

However, that *not* all that was needed. You see I also save the value from `requirejs.config` in `r` and then I use this `r` to load the modules. This is the same thing you would do if you used RequireJS [contexts](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#multiversion): you'd save the value of the `requirejs.config` call for each context so that you can use one function to load things from one context and the other to load things from the other context. I have to admit I don't know why this makes the code work. It smells like a bug to me.

Another thing I discovered is that `requirejs.optimize` swallows any exception thrown in its completion callback. This is definitely a bug. If it ha not been swallowing exceptions, you'd have had a better idea of what was going on.

Here is the code:

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

var requirejs = require('requirejs');

var r = requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    nodeRequire: require
});

requirejs.optimize({
    baseUrl: path.join(__dirname, 'foo'),
    dir: 'build',
    // You should do this to make sure that you are not accidentally loading
    // files that have *not* been combined.
    removeCombined: true,
    modules: [{
        name: 'main',
        include: [ 'src/bar' ]
    }]
}, function (data) {
    // console.log(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'main.js'), 'utf-8'));
    var main = r('main');
    console.log(main);
    var bar = r('src/bar');
    console.log(bar);
}, function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```